# Infinite geometric progression involving square terms

Tags: elementary-number-theory

The sum of an infinite geometric progression is 15 and the sum the squares of these terms is 45. Find the series. 
The formula for sum of infinite GP is $\frac{a }{1-r} $ and I got two equations $15=\frac {a}{1-r} $ snd $45=\frac {a^2}{1-r^2} $. Solving I got $3=\frac{a}{1+r} $

Answer (score 1):

Now it is almost over. From the equation you got, we have $a=3(1+r)$. From your first equation, $a=15(1-r)$. Two linear equations in two unknowns. Solve. From $15(1-r)=3(1+r)$ we find $r$.

Answer (score 0):

Clearly, $a\ne0, r^2\ne1$

We have $\displaystyle\frac{\dfrac{a^2}{1-r^2}}{\left(\dfrac a{1-r}\right)^2}=\frac{1-r}{1+r}$

But, $\displaystyle\frac{\dfrac{a^2}{1-r^2}}{\left(\dfrac a{1-r}\right)^2}=\frac{45}{15^2}=\frac15$

Now apply [Componendo and dividendo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Componendo_and_dividendo)

Answer (score 0):

I think the formula of sum to infinity of squared numbers is wrong in the first place. Use this formula...Sum_sq=a/(1-r^2)

Comment: $\frac{a^2}{1-r^2}$ is correct. The first term is also squared. You also haven't answered the rest of the question. OP wants to know what to do after applying these formulae for the sums of the geometric progression.